# Built phonegap application for blackberry and windows phone

Tags: windows, blackberry, cordova

Hii i am new in phonegap and i want to built my first application for iOS, Android, blackberry and window.I just want to know for blackberry and window what things i need for build blackberry and windows in devices. like xcode for iOS and Eclipse for Android. Also is there any online project apk or simulator available for all in one, and if not then separate for all

Answer (score 1):

Simply upload your HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript assets to the [PhoneGap™ Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) cloud service and they do the work of compiling for you (for all environments)!

Comment: Is it possible for all platforms from cloud with webservices urls also

Comment: It is possible for all platforms, yes. What exactly do you mean with 'with webservices urls also'?

Comment: yes in my application i attached webservices also, then it will work i think it will work, will it with webservices ?

Comment: if you want to call some webservices from your application.. sure it will work! ;)